# Globs & NPM Minimatch: Match all files and directories recursively except for specific directories

Tags: node.js, bash, glob, minimatch, grunt-ssh

Given the directory structure:

```
/Users/doge/very/amaze.js
/usr/local/bin/wow
/node_modules/
/css/
/css/somefile.css
/lib/
/somelib/
/anotherlib/somedir/finallib.js
/index.html
/somefile.test
/somelib/file.html
/firstdir/seconddir/file.css
/node_modules.txt
```

How would I only exclude the node_modules directory using extglob?

```
/!(node_modules)
```

The above matches everything at the root level except the node_modules directory and text file (which we want to include).  It also doesn't follow matching directories recursively.

```
/!(node_modules)/**
```

This one is closer, but it also excludes all of the files in the root directory.  Even if it included files at the root level, I'm guessing it would exclude the node_modules.txt file.

P.S. This is for file matching using [grunt-ssh](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh) and [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) node modules.

Comment: Have you tried this one `/!(node_modules){,/**}`

Comment: Hi Larry, I actually came to that conclusion a while ago but forgot I had asked this question on SO.  If you want to officially respond with this as the answer, I'll give you the upvote.

Comment: Thanks, @craignewkirk, an official answer can make this question perfectly, and easy to find for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one can solve your problem: `/!(node_modules){,/**}`